# Question about IPhone app bundle reasonable size for App Store. Storage memory!

Tags: iphone

I plan to submit my new app to App Store. App consist of a lot of image resources (animation)  - more than 40M. 
Is there any formal limits at App Store of the app bundle size? I never see such condition and think it will be ok. Is it right?

My major question is.. 
Is there any negative aspects for usability in case app is a huge? 
-increase user traffic 
-problem with installation 
-etc...

Should I try to reduce my app size as much as I can? (actually I've done it already but size still big)

I have no statistic on this point. What is the average app size at app store and how many exclusion with big size?

Thanks, Mike/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only limit that I'm aware of is that if your app is larger than 10 megabytes, you must download it over wifi when installing via the App Store on the phone.

There are some huge apps that I've installed, including:

- Apple's Hold em: 172.8 MB
- Spore: 68.5 MB
- Oregon Trail: 52.6 MB
- and 10 more that are over 40MB

I'd venture to guess that the upcoming Tom Tom app with the maps will be *very large*.

I don't think most people look at app size when downloading via iTunes or even on the phone when on Wifi. Smaller applications will install faster, but at that point they've already bought the application.

If you somehow have the ability to get your app under 10MB, then I'd say shoot for it. I don't have any actual numbers, but I would guess it certainly wouldn't hurt. However, if you can't get down to 10MB, I would spend only a reasonable amount of time getting your application size down. The decrease in download time and disk space I doubt will raise sales that much.

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer. Really helpful for me. Could you please point me any source where 10mb limit  described (need wifi)?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not easily found on Apple's site. However, it comes from WWDC 2008 (http://www.engadget.com/2008/06/09/steve-jobs-keynote-live-from-wwdc-2008/) at the 11:11 AM time spot: "If your app is 10MB or less, they can download it over cell, WiFi, or iTunes -- if it's over 10MB they can get it on WiFi or iTunes. So that's the App Store. We think there's never been anything like it."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any limits, but remember that anything larger than 10 MB requires a wifi connection to download.  Under 10 MB can be downloaded over 3G.

At least these are the limits today, they could change soon.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Connect developer guide says there is a hard limit of 2 GB.

Comment: That 2GB limit is for an compressed or uncompressed app ?

Answer (score 0):

App Size Tips (For iOS Apps Only)
■ Apps can be as large as 2GB, but be aware of download times.
■ Make efforts to minimize file size.
■ Remember there is a 20MB limit for Over the Air downloads

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf