# What is the resource size limit for iPhone native apps?

Tags: iphone, bundle

I have created iphone application to play some video files. I kept all the video files in application bundle. I want to know that what is the upper limit of resource size that we can put on resource?

In my case the total video file size is 500 MB. Is 500 MB is ok with iphone application?

Thanks,
Jim.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564859/whats-the-limit-for-the-size-of-iphone-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the answer to the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987737/question-about-iphone-app-bundle-reasonable-size-for-app-store-storage-memory/987759#987759).

Have in mind that downloading and installing such large app may be real pain for users.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen apps that big in the store before. Users don't like it as gh install process needs 2x the size of the app, but it works.

You can also try compressing the video more or streaming it for better size. There is a 10mb limit for ota downloads, so remember that too as many users only download ota.

Comment: I believe this is bumped up to 50mb now on data, and unlimited on wifi.